# Create deep object from string like "obj.obj1.obj2.data'

Tags: javascript

I'm starting with unit testing. I need to create some fake data to run the tests. So let's say inside a stubbed method I'm passing an `obj` as an argument and I do things with `obj.obj1.obj2.data` inside the function. Is there a way to set this fake object? So, given:

`obj.obj1.obj2.data`

It creates:

```
obj = {
  obj1: {
   obj2: {
     data: 'whatever'}}}
```

So it would be at the end something like:

`var obj = creator('obj.obj1.obj2.data', 20);`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the string is only a set of objects (no arrays) this should be fairly straightforward. Just split the input string on `.` and then use a while loop to do the nesting.

```js
function creator(str,val){
  var tree = str.split('.');
  var ret = {};
  var cur = ret;
  while(tree.length){
    var name = tree.shift();
    cur[name] = tree.length ? {} : val;
    cur = cur[name];
  }
  return ret;
}

document.querySelector("#out").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(creator('obj.obj1.obj2.data',20));
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else in interested, I created a simple npm module with the function below (https://github.com/r01010010/zappy) check it out:

```
var objFrom = function(str, last_value){

  var objs = str.split('.');
  var r = {};
  var last = r;

  for(i=0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    if(i !== objs.length - 1){
      last = last[objs[i]] = {};
    }else{
      last[objs[i]] = last_value;
    }
  }


  return r;


}

var obj = objFrom('obj1.obj2.data', 20);


console.log(obj.obj1.obj2.data);
```